# Angular Validators Only Working Sometimes But Stop after Restart and Recompile

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Can Someone Tell me why sometimes my code does this after its been running for a while. But then when I restart the Angular server it doesn't do it?[This is how I want it to look but when it comes back after a restart it's gone. Without changing any code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZO7f.png) I'm talking about the little Pop Up that says please fill out this field

this is my register.component.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<div class = "register-form">

    <form [formGroup] = "form" (ngSubmit) = "onSubmit()" class = "register-container">

        <h1> Register </h1>
        
        <div class = "form-group">
            <label for = "username">
                <b>
                    Username
                </b>
            </label>
            <input type = "text" formControlName = "username" class = "form-control" placeholder= "Enter Username" required maxlength="15" 
            [ngClass] = "{'is-invalid': submitted && f.username.errors}" >
            
            <div *ngIf = "submitted && f.username.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                <div *ngIf="f.username.errors.required">Username is required</div>
            </div>

                 


            <label for = "psw"> <b> Password </b> </label>
            <input type = "password" formControlName = "password" class = "form-control"
                 placeholder="Enter Password" required maxlength="20">


            <label for = "email"> <b> Email </b> </label>

            <input type = "email" formControlName = "email" class = "form-control"
                 placeholder = "Enter Email" required>
            



            <label for = "firstName"> <b> First Name </b> </label>

            <input type = "firstName" formControlName = "firstName" class = "form-control"
                 placeholder = "Enter First Name" required maxlength="15">



            <label for = "lastName"> <b> Last Name </b> </label>

            <input type = "lastName" formControlName = "lastName" class = "form-control"
                 placeholder = "Enter Last Name" required maxlength="15"> 

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Create</button>

        </div>

    </form>

</div>
```

this is my register.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

import {AccountService} from './account.service'

import {Router} from '@angular/router'



@Component({ 
    templateUrl: 'register.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['register.component.css']
 })
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
    form: FormGroup;
    loading = false;
    submitted = false;


    constructor(
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private accountService: AccountService,
        private router: Router
        ) { }

    
    ngOnInit() {
        this.form = this.formBuilder.group({       
            firstName: ['' , Validators.maxLength(15)],
            lastName: ['', Validators.maxLength(15)],
            username: ['', Validators.maxLength(15)],
            password: ['', Validators.maxLength(20)],
            email: ['', Validators.email]
        });
    }

    // convenience getter for easy access to form fields
    get f() { return this.form.controls; }

    onSubmit() {
        this.submitted = true;
        

        // stop here if form is invalid
        if (this.form.invalid) {
            console.log(this.form.value)
            return; 
            
        }
        this.accountService.register(this.form.value)
        console.log("Is This BS Working??", this.form.value)
        
    }

    onReset() {
        this.submitted = false;
        this.form.reset();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular adds  `novalidate` attribute to all forms by default. if you want native validation [ngNativeValidate](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm#native-dom-validation-ui) attribute on form element

```
 <form [formGroup] = "form" (ngSubmit) = "onSubmit()" class = "register-container" ngNativeValidate>
  ...
 </form>
```

Comment: THANK YOU! Do you have any idea why it would only do that sometimes? It was super frustrating trying to figure out what was causing it.

Comment: If it possible can you create stackblitz?